# dynamically add rows and maintain values on refresh

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a VF page that I can dynamically add rows to a pageBlockTable when clicking a button "Add Participant".  I have the page working where I can add the rows, but I'm losing the values in the row when I add a new row.  The values get cleared.

Can anyone help on how I can maintain my values when I add new rows?  I'm using a wrapper class.

Here is my page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Call_Report__c" extensions="CallReportControllerExtension" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Call Report Edit" subtitle="{!IF(isEditMode, 'New Call Report', CallReportName)}" />

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryUI, '/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')}" /> 
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryUI, '/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js')}" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function(){
        j$('.errorMsg').hide();
    });
</script> 
<script> 
var newWin=null; 
function openLookupPopup(name, id) 
{ 
    var url="/apex/ParticipantSearchPopup?namefield=" + name + "&idfield=" + id; 
    newWin=window.open(url, 'Popup','height=350,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no'); 
    if (window.focus) 
    { 
        newWin.focus(); 
    } 
    return false; 
} 

function closeLookupPopup() 
{ 
    if (null!=newWin) 
    { 
        newWin.close(); 
    } 
} 
</script>    
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages id="Errors" />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Call Report Edit" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theSaveButton" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" id="theCancelButton" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Call_Report__c.Name}" required="true" />
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!!isEditMode}" >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Owner" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Call_Report__c.Owner.Name}"  />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!isEditMode}" >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Owner" />
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Call_Report__c.Location__c}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Call_Report__c.EventAmount__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Detail" columns="1">
            <apex:inputTextArea value="{!Call_Report__c.Purpose__c}" cols="75" />
            <apex:inputTextArea value="{!Call_Report__c.Results__c}" cols="75" />
            <apex:inputTextArea value="{!Call_Report__c.Next_Steps__c}" cols="75" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Call_Report__c.Description__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock >           
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" id="topButton">
            <apex:commandButton id="newButton" value="Add Participant" action="{!addParticipant}" rerender="pageTable" immediate="true" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Participants" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="pageTable" value="{!participantLinesForPage}" var="part">
                <apex:column headerValue="Account" width="25%">
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!part.participantLine.Account__r.Id}" id="targetAccountId" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!part.participantLine.Account__r.Name}" id="targetAccountName" onFocus="this.blur()" disabled="false" style="width:175px;" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="openLookupPopup('{!$Component.targetAccountName}', '{!$Component.targetAccountId}'); return false" ><img onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" class="lookupIcon" src="/s.gif" /></a>                    
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Contact" width="25%">
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!part.participantLine.Contact__r.Id}" id="targetContactId" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!part.participantLine.Contact__r.Name}" id="targetContactName" onFocus="this.blur()" disabled="false" style="width:175px;" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="openLookupPopup('{!$Component.targetContactName}', '{!$Component.targetContactId}'); return false" ><img onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" class="lookupIcon" src="/s.gif" /></a>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="User" width="25%">
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!part.participantLine.User__r.Id}" id="targetUserId" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!part.participantLine.User__r.Name}" id="targetUserName" onFocus="this.blur()" disabled="false" style="width:175px;" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="openLookupPopup('{!$Component.targetUserName}', '{!$Component.targetUserId}'); return false" ><img onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" class="lookupIcon" src="/s.gif" /></a>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Spent Amount" width="25%">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!part.participantLine.Spent_Amount__c}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>                
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public with sharing class CallReportControllerExtension {

private final Call_Report__c callReport;

public Boolean isEditMode {get; set;}
public List<Participants> participantLinesForPage {get; set;}

public CallReportControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.callReport = (Call_Report__c)stdController.getRecord();
    isEditMode = isEditPage(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('save_new'));
    refreshLineItems();
}

public String getCallReportName() {
    return [select Name from Call_Report__c where Id =: callReport.Id].Name;
}

public PageReference addParticipant() {
    Participant__c newRecord = new Participant__c();
    //newRecord.Account__c      = '001f0000007qcD5';
    //newRecord.Contact__c      = '003f0000007H61z';
    //newRecord.User__c             = '005f0000000U5ME';
    //newRecord.Spent_Amount__c     = 100.00;
    participantLinesForPage.add(new Participants(participantLinesForPage.size(), newRecord));
    return null;
}

private void refreshLineItems() {
    List<Participant__c> lineItems = [select Account__c, Account__r.Id, Account__r.Name, Contact__c, Contact__r.Id, Contact__r.Name, User__c, User__r.Id, User__r.Name, Spent_Amount__c from Participant__c where Call_Report__c =: callReport.Id];

    participantLinesForPage = new List<Participants>();

    Integer iterate = 0;
    for(Participant__c p : lineItems) {
        participantLinesForPage.add(new Participants(iterate, p));
        iterate += 1;
    }
}

private Boolean isEditPage(String param) {
    Boolean retval = false;
    if(param != null) {
        retval = true;
    }
    return retval;
}

class Participants {    
    public Integer iterate {get; set;}
    public Participant__c participantLine {get; set;}

    public Participants(Integer iterate, Participant__c participantLine) {
        this.iterate = iterate;
        this.participantLine = participantLine;
    }
}
}
```

The data won't be saved until the save button is clicked, which I haven't implemented yet.  I'm just trying to get the values to maintain their state when new rows are added.  The refreshLineItems method is clearning the values, but I need that method when records already exist.  So, my question is how do I maintain the values in the rows that haven't been saved to the database yet?  I was trying to handle it in my wrapper class, but haven't been successful.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you losing values becouse immediate="true" tag in apex:commandButton.
You can use  and "required=false" in inputField instead.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response.  I tried removing the `immediate="true"` from the command button and I also removed the `required="false"` attribute from the inputField.  The values still got cleared.  Interestingly, I have one field that is not a lookup that is the pageBlockTable and its value isn't cleared.  It is only the lookup fields that the value gets cleared?  I'm not sure why the viewstate isn't maintaining those values?